# php artisan serve keeps working even after i shut the process down windows

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

i am trying to stop serving one project and moving to another . but my php artisan serve keeps loading the old project . i looked every where there is no process of php running and i even deactivated all the services in wamp but yet again the `localhost:8000` loads the site .
i know i may use this command `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` to server my project on other port but i want to know where is the problem and how to solve it because i want to switch between my projects a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all try `ctrl+c`, if it doesn't work then try below solution in command window

You can kill the port number

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:port_number)
```

for example, if it is running on 8000, you can write

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
```

and then restart wamp or xamp server

Comment: lsof : The term 'lsof' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.

Comment: just to let u know i am using windows . how can i check port 8000 in windws ?